# My delegate doesn't display checkboxes

Tags: c++, qt

Guys I've implemented my delegate class based on `QStyledItemDelegate` and the problem I have is that it doesn't display checkboxes next to the text which is displayed in the listView.

Before I've used my delegate I've those checkboxes displayed in my listView so I know that's the problem lays in this delegate class.
Any thoughts?

EDIT

```
void Display_Delegate::paint( QPainter* painter,
                              const QStyleOptionViewItem& option,
                              const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QString model_data = index.data().toString();
    QFontMetrics metrics = view_->fontMetrics();
    int view_width = view_->width();
    auto modified_str = adjust_text(metrics,model_data,view_width);//this just makes the string to fit into view, don't bother about it.
    QStyleOptionViewItemV4 style_option = option;
    initStyleOption(&style_option,index);
    QPalette::ColorGroup color_group = style_option.state & QStyle::State_Selected ? QPalette::Active : QPalette::Inactive;
    if (style_option.state & QStyle::State_Selected)
    {
        // painter->setPen(style_option.palette.color(color_group, QPalette::Highlight));
        painter->setBackgroundMode(Qt::OpaqueMode);

        QColor color(148,231,245,100);
        painter->setBackground(QBrush(color));
    }
    else
    {
        painter->setPen(style_option.palette.color(color_group, QPalette::Text));
    }

    painter->drawText(option.rect,modified_str);
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking of a tall banana daiquiri right now. How about yourself? Oh, and maybe a dream world where people with programming problems post their code.

Comment: @KerrekSB ok, I'll post code for paint fnc in my delegate, no problem. You may assume that model and proxy model are implemented correctly (they are and they work correctly with dflt delegate)

Comment: @KerrekSB funny how people are quick to give +1 even though this +1 was given after I actually edited my OP, don't you think?

Comment: What part of that code is supposed to draw checkboxes? Where do you set HasCheckIndicator?

Comment: @stark I don't draw it anywhere for the reason that I don't know where, I didn't even know that I have to set something. Would you mind to elaborate, and help me with this?

Comment: @smallB Re "+1", it is because this is always true, and we assume you didn't post any code at some point.

Comment: You could always check how the default implementation achieves this. Look in the Qt source in the common style. I don't have it available here but look for the drawControl method in the "common" style.

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
Qt::CheckState QStyleOptionViewItemV4::checkState
```

If this view item is checkable, i.e., `ViewItemFeature::HasCheckIndicator` is true, `checkState` is true if the item is checked; otherwise, it is false.

I found in the methods this fairly obscure reference to having a check indicator.  It says that if you want to make the item "checkable" then set this [style option](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstyleoptionviewitemv2.html#ViewItemFeature-enum).  So try something like:

```cpp
style_option.ViewItemFeatures = QStyleOptionViewItemV2::HasCheckIndicator;
```